# Regex to accept filename with single dot

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I am trying to build a regex which will validate the filename having single dot and filename has three parts separated by underscore

This is my regex below:

```
(?<appname>[^_]*)_(?<eventtype>[^_]*)_(?<counter>[^_]*).*
```

Input String

ABA_ABA_2015_478.csv - Should fail

ABA_ABA_2015478.js.csv - Should fail

ABC_BCD_XYZ.js - Should pass

Please help me with this.

Comment: `^(?<appname>[^_]*)_(?<eventtype>[^_]*)_(?<counter>[^_]*)\.[^_.]*$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
^(?<appname>[^_.]+)_(?<eventtype>[^_.]+)_(?<counter>[^._]*)\.[^.]+$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wsryCq/2)

If you're using `matches()` method in Java then you don't need to use anchors as anchors are implicit.

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?<appname>[^_.]+)`: Match and group any character of 1+ length that is not `_` and dot
- `(?<eventtype>[^_.]+)`: Match and group any character of 1+ length that is not `_` and dot
- `_`: Match a `_`
- `(?<counter>[^._]*)`: Match and group any character of 1+ length that is not `_` and dot
- `\.`: Match a dot
- `[^.]+`: Match any character of 1+ length that is not dot
- `$`: End

For Java use:

```
final String re = "^(?<appname>[^_.]+)_(?<eventtype>[^_.]+)_(?<counter>[^._]*)\\.[^.]+$";
```

Comment: Sorry sir, you are late, and also wrong :) I am still a step ahead with removing dots from the left part as well. Nice demo tho, I remember using it a lot.

Comment: Well, the left part can still contain dots. Though they would need to appear in appname or eventtype, you actually removed it from counter where it is most likely to cause any trouble.

Answer (score 0):

In regex, the dot character means "any character". You need to escape it using backslash (well, in Java, you need to double the backslash to escape the backslash itself in the Java string).

So, for the right part, something like `\.\w+` could do, if you also want some characters to follow the dot. Also, in the left part, exclude dot from the parts - `[^_.]*` (or `[^_.]+` for non-empty).